# "I accept my fault." vs "I accept it was my fault."

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, register

English is not my first language, but the first sentence (I accept my fault) doesn't sound very natural to me. I have looked up the word *accept* in several dictionaries and haven't found any similar example. It is often used with *responsibility* or *blame*. Another word that seems to convey the same meaning is *admit*, but that sounds a little formal and serious. What is the most natural way of saying that you are responsible for something wrong? Personally, the second sentence (I accept it is/was my fault/mistake.) sounds more natural to me.

Answer (score 1):

`"I accept my fault"` implies that you are admitting that you were at fault at a given point.

As defined in Oxford English Dictionary:

> An unattractive or unsatisfactory feature, especially in a piece of work or in a person's character.

`"I accept it was my fault"` indicates that a specific result was produced because of your mistake. It should also be noticed that, here, you might be trying to say that the said result was not caused by someone else's error and that you were responsible. The previous statement signifies characteristic while this one hints responsibility.

Another definition of the word "fault" in Oxford English Dictionary:

> Responsibility for an accident or misfortune.

Source: https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/fault

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Do you have any references to back up your thoughts? These references would bolster your opinion and improve the quality of your answer.

Comment: Hello, Qumber."It was my fault and I accept it" doesn't sound natural to my ears, and would probably mean "It was my fault – I accept that", echoing the statement to show sincerity.

Comment: @Qumber It seems you misread the question. It's not "I accept it it was my fault". My second sentence is "I accept (that) it was my fault.".

Comment: @rajah9 Thank you.  I added a source as you suggested.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You're right. I probably would say that a little differently too. I edited my answer to make things clearer. Thanks for pointing that out. 

Comment: @KaptanSingh That was a typing error. I understand that your second sentence states that the person is admitting to have made a mistake. I edited my answer. Thanks for bringing it to my attention. 